# Change at once schema in ML Studio

Tags: azure, ml-studio

I have some csv that contains null values for the first thousand of rows in some columns. The file has more than 200 columns. ML Studio is infering the schema as strings, but in reality all of those columns are decimals. How can I change all of those at once instead of going 1 by 1?

[image]

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: You can find `skip row` option before altering schema, there you skip first 1000  or 900 rows to get `Decimal`.

Comment: @JayashankarGS but by doing that I'll remove my columns name no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the table I have, with the first 1000 rows being null and the remaining rows containing decimal data.

```markdown
| Column_1 | Column_2 | Column_3 | Column_4 | Column_5 | Column_6 | Column_7 | Column_8 | Column_9 | Column_10 |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-----------|
|          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |           |
|          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |           |
|          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |           |
|          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |           |
|          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |           |
|          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |           |
|          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |           |
|          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |          |           |
```

```markdown
|                    |                    |                   |                    |                   |                   |                    |                    |                   |                     |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|--------------------|-------------------|-------------------|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|---------------------|
| 3.0734454878622133 | 7.273655602933219  | 6.422759017554442 | 1.2375730442349464 | 8.300633975042667 | 9.416728718037973 | 7.078674510546692  | 4.9788718688395415 | 5.423851215824898 | 0.28440799036452913 |
| 5.405178011983812  | 3.6230982150244015 | 9.440586438993723 | 9.394297741890705  | 9.855264171698582 | 7.132510908305499 | 3.4916472430982948 | 8.34951022213561   | 3.51424491309551  | 8.15558468010132    |
```

Inside the file the data looks like below.

[image]

While creating a data asset in ML Studio, use the following configurations:

1. **File format** - Set the file format as **Delimited**.
2. **Delimiter** - Set the delimiter accordingly. **Eg** :- Comma.
3. **Column headers** - Select the headers appropriately.
4. **Skip rows** - Choose whether to skip rows from the first file or all files.
5. **Skip n rows** - In skip rows, specify about 900 rows to skip.

The default settings determine how the data is parsed.
It takes a subset of your data and determines the schema.
Make sure your data is included in that subset by skipping some null rows.

[image]

All column types have changed.

[image]

Before skipping the rows, the subset contained only null values, so it automatically recognized them as `string`. Try skipping a number of rows according to the data you have.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your answer, when i do that, my column names are erased as you can see in my psot (last image)

Comment: Provide the data in the file like how I given in this solution. Helpful for reproducing the issue.

Comment: And how many files you have?

Comment: just one .csv file

Comment: Ok provide the sample data how it is in  .csv file